# Can I prevent a integer overflow in C# using an unsigned right shift?

Tags: c#, bit-shift, integer-overflow

I want alwaysPositive to be assigned a positive number with all possible values for lareValue1 and largeValue2 (these are at least 1).

The following statement causes a buffer overflow:

```
int alwaysPositive = (largeValue1 + largeValue2) / 2;
```

I know I can prevent it by substracting and adding:

```
int alwaysPositive = largeValue1 + ((largeValue2 - largeValue1) / 2);
```

But in other programming languages I can use an unsigned bitshift to do the trick:

```
int alwaysPositive3 = (largeValue1 + largeValue2) >>> 1;
```

How can I do this in C#?

---

The answers below all solve the problem. There are probably lots of ways to do this, but they all (including my solutions) have one thing in common: they all look obfuscated.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why would you want to do this though?

Comment: The reason I tried to do this is reinventing the wheel: implementing a binary search. Why would I write my own version? I don't know...

Comment: Just FYI, your code samples do different things.  I think you want parentheses in the first one.  PS. Were you inspired by http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html ?

Comment: I was actually inspired by the book "datastructures and algorithms" that was doing it wrong in java.

Answer (score 3):

```
int alwaysPositive = (largeValue1 >> 1) + (largeValue2 >> 1) + (largeValue1 & largeValue2 & 0x01);
```

The idea behind the above is that if you pre-divide the results before you add them, then you will avoid the overflow as both high-order bits will be unset. You then add some slight correction logic to increase the value by one if both were positive (round down). If you only care if either one was positive (round off) then you could change it to

```
int alwaysPositive = (largeValue1 >> 1) + (largeValue2 >> 1) + ((largeValue1 | largeValue2) & 0x01);
```

Answer (score 3):

`unchecked((largeValue1 + largeValue2) >> 1)` is another option.

See the documentation for the [unchecked keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8.aspx).

Comment: I don't believe this works. All it does is remove the checking that flags that you have a problem. It doesn't actually remove the problem.

Comment: I doubt there are many things that only work for unsigned integers. CPUs generally treat signed values the same as signed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
  x = largeValue1;
  y = largeValue2; 
  return (x&y)+((x^y)/2);
```

That's a bit-twiddling way to get the average of two integers without overflow.

If you want you can replace the division by two with a bit-shift, but the compiler will do that for you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You could use uints:

```
uint alwaysPositive = (uint)(largeValue1 + largeValue2) / 2;
```

Comment: This will still overflow. The addition overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Not to nitpick, but you mean "integer overflow" rather than "buffer overflow".

I don't know C#, so there may be another way, but you could mimic an unsigned shift by just masking off the top bit:  (x >> 1) & 0x80000000

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
    checked { alwaysPositive3 = (largeValue1 + largeValue2); }
}
catch (OverflowException ex)
{
   // Corrective logic
}
```

Comment: also, if this were in an inner loop of an algorithm it could really slow it down